# If Parent Show.... ElseIf Child Show... On same page?

Tags: php

I have a custom post type of 'editors' which is working fine.

Each post type will have various child posts of the main editor parent.

On the single-editors.php page I need it to show x content if its the PARENT, but if its the CHILD show completely different content and ignore any parent content obviously.

This is what i have so far 'works' in regard to it shows the content on the Parent page, but then shows nothing on the child page.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- IF Parent Show Below -->

 <?php $this_page_id=$wp_query->post->ID; ?>

<?php query_posts(array('showposts' => 1, 'post_parent' => $this_page_id, 'post_type' => 'editors')); while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>


<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


<?php } ?>

<!-- IF Child Show Below ignore the above -->

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<section role="document">

<?php the_content(); ?>

</section>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm no good at conditionals so I wonder if its possible? As obviously all the content of the custom post has to appear on single-editors.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($post->post_parent == 0) {
    // has no parent, is parent
    get_template_part('single-editors', 'parent');
    } else {
    // child
    get_template_part('single-editors', 'children');
    }
```

won't work if you have more than 2 levels ( like parent->child->child ).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work :(

Only seems to show the template single-editors-children.php whether your on the parent page or child page..?

Any ideas, thanks for lookin :)

Comment: I'm not getting this to work either.  This would be an ideal solution.